# How to get started on ballerina composer?

Tags: ballerina

I was looking at the documentation provided in [here](http://ballerinalang.org/documentation/) at ballerinalang.org. This documentation is very helpful. But is there a documentation on introduction to the composer? any articles or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you had was for an old preview version of the docs, which did not contain much information on the Composer--sorry about that! We will redirect that URL ASAP.

Please go to [1] to access the latest User Guide and API Docs. In the User Guide, you can check out the Quick Tour and the Write your First Program tutorial to get started using Ballerina and the Composer.

[1] http://ballerinalang.org/docs/